# adding date columns in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have created one SSRS report.

In the report I am providing one parameter named `startDate`. From the `startDate` I have to display 10 columns like `week of dd-mon-yy`.

First column contains date of Monday in the week which the start date lies. then the upcoming 10 Mondays are used.

Example is shown in the image. How can I achieve this in SSRS reports. I need query and column value.

[image]

Comment: what's your main problem? to get data by weeks starting with monday from the week which contains startdate? or to pivot the data in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your column name alias for current week

```
select 'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0),106);
```

then alias for next weeks

```
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 1,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 2,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 3,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 4,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 5,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 6,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 7,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 8,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
select  'Week of '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dateadd(week, 9,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)),106);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get date of Monday in the week which the start date lies
along with the dates of next 10 mondays you can write a query as:

```
DECLARE @input date

SET @input = '12/29/2013'

SELECT 'Week of '+
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), 
        DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@input), T.week*7)
        , 106), ' ', '-')
FROM 
(VALUES (-1),(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8))AS T(week)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/165)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to get Monday in the week which the start date lies for first week:

```
=Dateadd(DateInterval.Day, 
        (0 * 7) + 1 - DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Parameters!startDate.Value, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), 
        Parameters!startDate.Value)
```

For second week:

```
=Dateadd(DateInterval.Day, 
        (1 * 7) + 1 - DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Parameters!startDate.Value, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), 
        Parameters!startDate.Value)
```

And so on.